# How to create an oracle procedure to find out the distinct records from duplicate and update

Tags: oracle, procedure

I want to know the how can i create an oracle procedure to find out the distinct records from whole table and insert into same table by updating value of another column
Suppose the table name is temp and below is the structure of the table

```
| id         | address              |  key  |ver_id
| 1          | 242  Street          |  123  | 1 
| 2          | 242 Street           | 123   |2
| 3          | 242  Street          |  123  |3
| 4          | 242 Long St          | 456   |4
```

So,how to write a oracle procedure to select 1 record from first 3 rows for above columns which is duplicate and insert that distinct record at the end of the table by updating ver_id as -1  like below:

```
| id         | address              |  key  |ver_id**
|  1         | 242  Street          |  123  | 1 
| 2          | 242 Street           | 123   |2
| 3          | 242  Street          |  123  |3
| 4          | 242 Long St          | 456   |4
|  5         | 242  Street          |  123  |-1
```

I have tried to write the simple procedure to find out the duplicates from table

```
create or replace PROCEDURE demo (
    key1 IN VARCHAR2
) AS
    CURSOR c_temp IS
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        temp
    WHERE
        key = key1;
 r_temp c_temp%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_temp;
    LOOP
        FETCH c_temp INTO r_temp;
        EXIT WHEN c_temp%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line('id: '
                             || r_temp.id
                             || ' address: '
                             || r_temp.address);

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE c_temp ;
END;
```

But above procedure is just fetch the records with duplicate records, but i need help to write the procedure to select distintct records from duplicate and insert into same table with different ver_id as -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say how is `id` column supposed to get its value, so I just created a sequence.

This is sample data:

```
SQL> select * from temp order by id;

        ID ADDRESS            KEY     VER_ID
---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
         1 242 street         123          1
         2 242 street         123          2
         3 242 street         123          3
         4 242 long st        456          4

SQL> create sequence seq_temp start with 5;

Sequence created.
```

You don't need PL/SQL procedure for what you're doing; a SQL statement is enough:

- `data` CTE finds duplicates (their `rn` value is larger than 1)
- `data2` fetches distinct rows. Why? Because you can't use a sequence along with `distinct`
- the final `select` composes values that should be inserted

So:

```
SQL> insert into temp (id, address, key, ver_id)
  2  with data as
  3    (select t.*,
  4       row_number() over (partition by address, key order by id) rn
  5     from temp t
  6    ),
  7  data2 as
  8    (select distinct d.address, d.key
  9     from data d
 10     where d.rn > 1
 11    )
 12  select seq_temp.nextval, address, key, -1
 13  From data2;

1 row created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from temp order by id;

        ID ADDRESS            KEY     VER_ID
---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
         1 242 street         123          1
         2 242 street         123          2
         3 242 street         123          3
         4 242 long st        456          4
         5 242 street         123         -1         --> here it is

SQL>
```

Comment: According to above result, after inserting distinct record with ver_id as -1, i also want to delete the duplicate recrods from table and update the ID for newly added record in parent table so how can we do that in the same query ?

Expected result be like this:

 select * from temp order by id;

        ID ADDRESS            KEY     VER_ID
---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
         4 242 long st        456          4
         5 242 street         123         -1         --> here it is

Comment: Parent table name as temp_address like below:
Before update-->

ADDR_ID  ver_ID            ID
---------- ----------- ---------- 
         1    1                1
         2    2                2
         3    3                3
         4    4                4
After update--> (here ID is primary key from temp table i.e foreign key of temp_address table 
  
ADDR_ID  ver_ID            ID
---------- ----------- ---------- 
         1    1                5
         2    2                5
         3    3                5
         4    4                4

Comment: You can't, not in the same query.

Comment: Ok. then how can i do it with different query?

Comment: It is not a "different" query but "separate DELETE statement".